# Jira4r Find users in a project

Tags: soap, jira

How do I find the users in a project or users in a group role for a project ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
project = @jira.getProjectByKey('PROJCODe')
devs = @jira.getProjectRoles[2]
@jira.getProjectRoleActors(devs,proj).roleActors[0].users
```

Comment: Please think about adding a comment to your "code only" answer.